# AWS rotate ip address on each request (api gateway + lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-scraping, proxy

I am creating a scraper that calls a public API. I want to have a pool of proxy IP's that I can use to send each request from. My request interval should be around 10s, and each IP is allowed to send a request every minute. So having a pool of 6 ip's would be sufficient.

My setup is a EC2 server that send a request to API Gateway which calls the lambda function.

Is there a way for me to set this up so that each lambda request is send from a different ip

So let's assume I start polling from 08:00:00

```
08:00:00 - 0.0.0.1
08:00:10 - 0.0.0.2
08:00:20 - 0.0.0.3
08:00:30 - 0.0.0.4
08:00:40 - 0.0.0.5
08:00:50 - 0.0.0.6
08:01:00 - 0.0.0.1
etc.
```

or am I completely looking in the wrong direction and is there a different way for me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The outbound requests from Lambda will come from different IP addresses as long as they're run on different instances of Lambda. You can have Lambda keep a minimum number of instances in a read to run state, for additional cost. But then you don't have a mechanism to route a specific request to a specific Lambda instance.

Since you're running an EC2 instance, you could bind multiple public IP addresses to it and then route each outbound request to the next one in turn.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have more information on the second solution you posted? (Mainly the "outbound request to the next one in turn" part)

Comment: That's specific to the language you're writing in. Node, python, php and others all their own way to specify what IP address to use for the outbound connection.